# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que al hacer logout no pueda volver atrás mediante el navegador? Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy intentando resolver este problema desde hace tiempo.
Me he mirado en muchos foros e intentado aplicar pequeñas soluciones que he encontrado pero han salido fallidas.

Este es mi controlador.

```
public function logoutUsuario(Request $request)
{
    /* Auth::guard('usuario')->logout();
    //$this->middleware('guest:usuario')->except('logout');

    $request->session()->flush();
    //$request->session()->regenerate();

    //return view('auth.Frontend.login');
    return redirect()->action('Auth\UsuarioLoginController@showLoginForm')->header('Cache-Control', 'nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
    ->header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
    ->header('Expires', 'Sat, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'); */
    Auth::guard('usuario')->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Y esta la ruta:

```
//Logout
Route::get('/logoutUsuario', 'Auth\UsuarioLoginController@logoutUsuario')->name('logoutUsuario');
```

El código comentado es lo que he usado para intentar solventar este problema pero no me ha servido o quizá lo estoy aplicando mal...